# AG GRID - how to trigger a button in a table cell with keyboard only?

Tags: javascript, angular, accessibility, ag-grid, keyboard-events

It is an accessibility issue. I use Angular. I decided to add an action column which consists of buttons. I can navigate to them using tab or arrows but I cannot trigger an action when I press 'space' or 'enter'. What am I missing?

I was experimenting with 'cellKeyPress' and 'cellKeyDown' but I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Could you share the relevant code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Grid Keyboard Navigation from the ARIA Authoring Practices Guide (APG)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/grid/#gridNav) suggests that if there are several interactive elements inside a grid cell, _Enter_ should be used to change into interactive mode for the cell. After that, arrows or focus will switch between these elements. _Escape_ will then leave interactive mode and allow grid navigation again. I cannot find a Demo for ag-grid with several buttons to verify if that’s how it’s done. Maybe you can…